# Error in \makecert in westernthesis.tex:

Tags: thesis, undefined

I get an error for the \makecert line in my latex thesis file in [westernthesis](https://grad.uwo.ca/doc/academic_services/thesis/templates/westernthesis.tex):

```
% \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Certificate of Examination}
% \makecert
```

Could anyone help? I receive an error saying:

[image]

P.S: This is all the code in the file:

```
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% University of Western Ontario Thesis Template
% By: Justin Quinn Veenstra, 2010
% With thanks to Mr. (soon to be Dr.) Will Robertson.


\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
%% Decomment next line to use PostScript fonts
%%\UsePackage{times}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                                                    %%
%%                    ***   I M P O R T A N T   ***                   %%
%%                                                                    %%
%% Fill in the following fields with the required information:        %%
%%  - \department{...}  name of the graduate department               %%
%%  - \degree{...}      name of the degree obtained                   %%
%%  - \author{...}      name of the author                            %%
%%  - \title{...}       title of the thesis                           %%
%%  - \gyear{...}       year of graduation                            %%
%%  - \super{...}    supervisor
%%  - \firstname, \middlename, \lastname... there is additional documentation by the actual fields, so I'll leave it at that
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[byname]{smartref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[verbose]{placeins}
%\usepackage{hyperref} %comment out for hardcopy
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\makeatletter
\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
\newenvironment{acknowledgements}%
{\clearemptydoublepage
 \begin{center}
  \section*{Acknowledgements}
 \end{center}
 \begingroup
}{\newpage\endgroup}

\newenvironment{dedication}%
{\clearemptydoublepage 
 \begin{center}
  \section*{Dedication}
 \end{center}
 \begingroup
}{\newpage\endgroup}

\newenvironment{preliminary}%
{\pagestyle{plain}\pagenumbering{roman}}%
{\pagenumbering{arabic}}

\addtoreflist{chapter}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{definition}[1][Definition]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{example}[1][Example]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{remark}[1][Remark]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}

\newcommand{\qed}{\nobreak \ifvmode \relax \else
      \ifdim\lastskip<1.5em \hskip-\lastskip
      \hskip1.5em plus0em minus0.5em \fi \nobreak
      \vrule height0.75em width0.5em depth0.25em\fi}

% Default values for title page.

%% To produce output with the desired line spacing, the argument of
%% \spacing should be multiplied by 5/6 = 0.8333, so that 1 1/2 spaced
%% corresponds to \spacing{1.5} and double spaced is \spacing{1.66}.
\def\spacing{1.66} % default line spacing


%% Define the "thesis" page style.
\if@twoside % If two-sided printing.
\def\ps@thesis{\let\@mkboth\markboth
   \def\@oddfoot{}
   \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
   \def\@oddhead{
      {\sc\rightmark} \hfil \rm\thepage
      }
   \def\@evenhead{
      \rm\thepage \hfil {\sc\leftmark}
      }
   \def\chaptermark##1{\markboth{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      Chapter\ \thechapter. \ \fi ##1}{}}
   \def\sectionmark##1{\markright{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
      \thesection. \ \fi ##1}}}
\else % If one-sided printing.
\def\ps@thesis{\let\@mkboth\markboth
   \def\@oddfoot{}
   \def\@oddhead{
      {\sc\rightmark} \hfil \rm\thepage
      }
   \def\chaptermark##1{\markright{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      Chapter\ \thechapter. \ \fi ##1}}}
\fi

\pagestyle{thesis}
% Set up page layout.
\setlength{\textheight}{9in} % Height of the main body of the text
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in} % .5" margin on top of page
\setlength{\headsep}{.5in}  % space between header and top of body
\addtolength{\headsep}{-\headheight} % See The LaTeX Companion, p 85
\setlength{\footskip}{.5in}  % space between footer and bottom of body
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.25in} % width of the body of the text
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.25in} % 1.25" margin on the left for odd pages
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in} % 1.25"  margin on the right for even pages

% Marginal notes
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{.75in} % width of marginal notes
\setlength{\marginparsep}{.125in} % space between marginal notes and text

% Make each page fill up the entire page. comment this out if you
% prefer. 
\flushbottom

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % Number the subsubsections 
\def\spacing{1.66} % default line spacing

\newcommand\isco[1]{%
  \edef\@tempa{#1}%
  \def\@tempb{}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
    \else \\\underline{Co-Supervisor:}\vspace{0.35in}\\\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\\{#1}\\
  \fi
}

\newcommand\isjoint[1]{%
  \edef\@tempa{#1}%
  \def\@tempb{}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
    \else \\\underline{Joint Supervisor:}\vspace{0.35in}\\\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\\{#1}\\
  \fi
}

\newcommand\isalt[1]{%
  \edef\@tempa{#1}%
  \def\@tempb{}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
    \else \\\underline{Alternate Supervisor:}\vspace{0.35in}\\\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\\{#1}\\
  \fi
}

\newcommand\isdefinedsig[1]{%
  \edef\@tempa{#1}%
  \def\@tempb{}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
    \else \\ \dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\\{#1}\\
  \fi
}
\newcommand\isdefinedspinetitle[1]{%
  \edef\@tempa{#1}%
  \def\@tempb{}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
    \else (Spine title: #1)\\
  \fi
}
\newcommand\coauthor[1]{%
  \edef\@tempa{#1}%
  \def\@tempb{}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
    \else \newpage \Large Co-Authorship Statement\normalsize\\\indent\\#1\\
  \fi
}

\newcommand\acknowlege[1]{%
  \edef\@tempa{#1}%
  \def\@tempb{}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
    \else \newpage \Large Acknowlegements\normalsize\\\indent\\#1\newpage
  \fi
}

%\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{\Huge \textbf{List of Appendices} \normalsize}
\newcommand{\blank}{\hspace{-2mm}}
\newcommand{\super}{Dr...} %supervisor
% \newcommand{\superj}{Dr. A. Manning} %joint supervisor, if there is one, leave blank if not (lbin)... only one of the three.
\newcommand{\superc}{} %co-supervisor, if there is one, leave blank if not (lbin)
\newcommand{\supera}{} %alternate supervisor, if there is one, leave blank if not (lbin)
\newcommand{\sco}{Dr. A}  %member of supervisory committee
\newcommand{\sct}{Dr. B}  %other member of supervisory committee (lbin)
\newcommand{\examo}{Dr. C}  %examining committee (up to four, if less leave blank)
\newcommand{\examt}{Dr. D}
\newcommand{\examth}{Dr. E}
\newcommand{\examf}{}
\newcommand{\department}{...}
\newcommand{\degree}{...}
\newcommand{\firstname}{...}
\newcommand{\middlename}{}
\newcommand{\lastname}{...}
%\renewcommand{\author}[1]{\ifx\empty#1\else\gdef\@author{#1}\fi} 
\newcommand{\authorname}{{\firstname} {\middlename} {\lastname}}
\newcommand{\titl}{title...}
\newcommand{\spinetitle}{title...}%only if the above is more than 60 characters
\newcommand{\thesisformat}{Monograph} %or Integrated Article
\newcommand{\gyear}{\number\year}
\newcommand{\makecoauthor}{
%Type information about coauthorship here/
I would like to acknowlege my imaginary friend, Jummi for doing all the work. 
}
\newcommand{\makeacknowlege} {
%Type in acknowlegements here
}
\newcommand{\listappendixname}{List of Appendices}
\newlistof{myappendices}{app}{\listappendixname}
\newcommand{\myappendices}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{app}{myappendices}{#1}\par}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}
{\begin{titlepage}
   \setcounter{page}{1}
   %% Set the line spacing to 1 for the title page.
   %\begin{spacing}{1} 
   \begin{large}
   \begin{center}
      \mbox{}
      \vfill
      {\MakeUppercase{\titl}}\\
      \isdefinedspinetitle{\spinetitle}
      (Thesis format: \thesisformat)\\
      \vfill
      by \\
      \vfill
      {\firstname} \underline{\lastname}\\
      \vfill
      Graduate Program in {\department}\\
      \vfill
        A thesis submitted in partial fulfillment\\
        of the requirements for the degree of\\
        \degree\\
        \vfill
        The School of Graduate and Postdoctoral Studies\\
        The University of Western Ontario\\
        London, Ontario, Canada\\
        \vfill
      {\copyright} {\authorname} {\gyear}  \\
      \vspace*{.2in}
   \end{center}
   \end{large}
%   \end{spacing}
   \end{titlepage}

}%\maketitle

\newcommand{\makecert}{%
   \setcounter{page}{2}
\vfill
\begin{center}
\large
THE UNIVERSITY OF WESTERN ONTARIO\\
School of Graduate and Postdoctoral Studies\\
\vfill
\textbf{CERTIFICATE OF EXAMINATION}
\end{center}

\vfill
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth} %tabular instead?
\begin{tabular}{l}
\underline{Supervisor:}\vspace{0.35in}
\isdefinedsig{\super}
\isco{\superc}
\isjoint{\superj}
\isalt{\supera}
\\
\underline{Supervisory Committee:}\vspace{0.35in}
\isdefinedsig{\sco}\vspace{0.15in}
\isdefinedsig{\sct}
\end{tabular}
\vfill
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5in}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\underline{Examiners:} \\\vspace{.5cm}
\isdefinedsig{\examo}\\
\isdefinedsig{\examt}\\
\isdefinedsig{\examth}\\
\isdefinedsig{\examf}
\end{tabular}
\vfill
\end{minipage}
\vfill
\end{table}
\vfill
\begin{center}
The thesis by \\ \vfill
\textbf{\firstname{} \middlename{} \underline{\lastname}}\\
\vfill
entitled:\\\vfill
\textbf{\titl}\\\vfill
is accepted in partial fulfillment of the \\
requirements for the degree of\\
\degree\\
\end{center}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\\
Date
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5in}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\\
Chair of the Thesis Examination Board
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\doublespacing
%% ***   NOTE   ***
%% You should put all of your '\newcommand', '\newenvironment', and
%% '\newtheorem's (in other words, all the global definitions that you
%% will need throughout your thesis) in a separate file and use
%% "\input{filename}" to input it here.




%% This sets the page style and numbering for preliminary sections.
\begin{preliminary}
%% This generates the title page from the information given above.
\maketitle
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Certificate of Examination}
\makecert
\newpage
% \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Co-Authorship Statement}
% \coauthor{\makecoauthor}  %comment this out if none
% \newpage
% \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowlegements}
% \acknowlege{\makeacknowlege}  %as above
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\Large\begin{center}\textbf{Abstract}\end{center}\normalsize
%%  ***  Put your Abstract here.   ***

\vfill
\textbf{Keywords:} %put your keywords here% 
\newpage
\tableofcontents\newpage
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables\newpage
% \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Appendices}
% \listofmyappendices\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations, Symbols, and Nomenclature}
\large{List of Abbreviations, Symbols, and Nomenclature} 
\normalsize 
\newpage
\end{preliminary}
%% End of the preliminary sections: reset page style and numbering.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                                                    %%
%%                    ***   I M P O R T A N T   ***                   %%
%%                                                                    %%
%% Put your Chapters here; the easiest way to do this is to keep each %%
%% chapter in a separate file and \include all the files right here.  %%
%% Note that each chapter file should start with the line             %%
%% "\chapter{ChapterName}".  Note that using "\include" instead of    %%
%% "\input" makes each chapter start on a new page.                   %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\include{Introduction}
\include{Background}
\include{Related_Work}
\include{Methodology}
\include{Evaluation_and_results}
\include{Discussion_Future_Works}


%% This adds a line for the Bibliography in the Table of Contents.
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
%% ***   Set the bibliography style.   ***
\bibliographystyle{plain} % (change according to your preference)
%%% ***   Set the bibliography file.   ***
\bibliography{westernthesis}{}
%% ***   NOTE   ***
%% If you don't use bibliography files, comment out the previous line
%% and use \begin{thebibliography}...\end{thebibliography}.  (In that
%% case, you should probably put the bibliography in a separate file
%% and \include or \input it here).

    

% %Appendices.
% \begin{appendices}
% \include{appendixa}
% \end{appendices}

     

%CV only relevant stuff... not full CV.
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Curriculum Vitae} 
\chapter*{Curriculum Vitae} 
\begin{table}[ht] 
\begin{tabular}{ll} 
\textbf{Name:} & name ...\\\\ 
\textbf{Post-Secondary} & university of ...\\     
\textbf{Education and}& city ...\\  
\textbf{Degrees:}& degree\\\\ 
\textbf{Honours and}& \\ 
\textbf{Awards:}& \\\\ 
\textbf{Related Work}& \\ 
\textbf{Experience:}& \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 
% \subsubsection*{Publications:} 
% La La 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please avoid screenshots and reduce your LaTeX code into a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Answer (score 1):

As you show, `\superj` is used but not defined.

The definition is commented out

```
% \newcommand{\superj}{Dr. A. Manning} %joint supervisor, if there is one, leave blank if not (lbin)... only one of the three.`
```

uncomment that or use

```
\newcommand{\superj}{}
```

or whatever